# How can I make a color picker, choosing three differents colors?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I want to be able to choose three differents colors from a color picker. I want to choose between red, green and blue. How can I change my code below to do this? Should I have my color picker in its own class?

```
    public class SuperDraw extends Sprite
{
    private var loadImage:LoadImage;
    private var saveImage:SaveImage;
    private var graphic:GameGraphic;
    private var bmp:Bitmap;
    private var pencilDraw:Shape;
    private var p:Point;
    //private var backGroundGame:backGround;

    private var backGroundDraw:drawTabel;

    private static var penSprite:Sprite;
    private static var mouseDownFlag:Boolean;

    protected var penSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();    

    // Bitmap där ritandet sparas.
    protected var canvasBitmap:Bitmap;    

    public function SuperDraw()
    {   
        graphic = new GameGraphic();
        loadImage = new LoadImage();
        saveImage = new SaveImage();
        backGroundDraw = new drawTabel();

        //-------------------------------------------

        // Skapa en backgrund där ritandet ska visas.  
        this.canvasBitmap = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight ), "auto", true );

        // Adda alla klasser och ha graphic klassen ovanför penSprite.
        this.addChild(graphic);
        this.addChild(backGroundDraw);
        this.addChild(penSprite);
        this.addChild(saveImage);
        this.addChild(loadImage);

        this.penSprite.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000 );

        this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.mouseDown);
    }

    private function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.mouseMove);
        this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,   this.mouseUp);
    }

    private function mouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        penSprite.graphics.lineTo( e.localX, e.localY );
    }

    // Skapar funktionen mouseUp.
    private function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // Ritar och sparar till bitmapData.
        canvasBitmap.bitmapData.draw( penSprite, null, null, null, null, true );

        // Ta bort alla listeners. 
        this.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
        this.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,   mouseUp);
    }           
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no color picker in the code, neither any hint where/how you want to use it. 2) Your comments are not in English, so many people (including me) won't understand them.

Comment: yes, Its not a color picker in my code, that is what I want to have. I wanna be able to chosse from a color picker three different colors red, green and blue, and use the colors to draw.

Comment: So what is the question actually? "How to change the code below" is too generic. You don't know how to create a color palette with red, green, blue or you don't know how to detect mouse click on them, or you don't know how to store the selected color or what? And yes, you should have color picker in different class so that can be reused.

Comment: Why not have 3 different color pickers?

Comment: Yes, Its not a color picker in my code, that is what I want to have. I wanna be able to chosse from a color picker three different colors red, green and blue, and use the colors to draw.

Comment: So, how can I change my code, so I can use a color picker, using color red, green and blue. I dont know how to create a color picker palette ... Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want this

```
import fl.controls.ColorPicker;

var cp:ColorPicker = new ColorPicker();
cp.colors = [ 0xff0000,0x00ff00,0x0000ff];
addChild(cp);
```

for more info,you can visit http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/ColorPicker.html